# Python compare epoch time from a text file

Tags: python, datetime

How could I compare epoch time from a text file abc.txt with content below?

```
time:1485253570.376686
```

Condition: if current time is 5 minutes longer than 5 minutes, print "0", else print "1"

Comment: Looks like someone's task for homework... Show what you've tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use subtraction.

Get the current epoch, subtract the epoch from the file and check whether the result is more than 300 seconds.

```
import time

with open('abc.txt') as f:
    epoch = float(next(f).split(':')[1])

if time.time() - epoch > 300:
    print(0)
else:
    print(1)
```

or more succinctly:

```
print(0 if time.time() - epoch > 300 else 1)
```

Comment: may I know how does python handle those milliseconds number?

Comment: @ThomasG.Lau: Not sure what you mean by milliseconds, but the value returned by `time.time()` is seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC. The fractional part is fraction of a second. Multiply by 1000 to get milliseconds.